# Failure to terminate when expanding a list by applying a function to its members til no output is new

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

Using the Data.List.Ordered library, I was trying to express a function that expands a list by taking each element, applying a function to it and collecting the results in with the original elements without duplicates, and repeating that until no new elements are created. Now, looking at Data.Set, the union operation is O(n+m), and Data.List.Ordered's nubSort is O(n), so this probably doesn't even speed things up, but it didn't work, and I don't know why.

```
import Data.List.Ordered --install data-ordlist
```

Consider the following:

```
nextimg:: Ord a => (a->a)->[a]->[a]
nextimg f x = nubSort $ union (map f x) x
```

Note that

```
nextimg ((`mod` 3).(+1)) [1,2]
== nextimg ((`mod` 3).(+1)) [0,1,2]
== [0,1,2]
```

But if one attempts to perform this recursively:

```
orbit:: Ord a => (a->a)->[a]->[a]
orbit f x = orbit f ( nubSort $ union (map f x) x )
```

Then this will run forever:

```
orbit ((`mod` 3).(+1)) [1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, after you obtained the largest list, nubSort sorted it, and orbit keeps "unioning" only the elements that are already there, and sorting the list that was already sorted. You didn't specify a termination condition - like, possibly:

```
orbit f x | y == x    = x -- fixed point was found
          | otherwise = orbit f y where
            y = nubSort $ union (map f x) x
```

Comment: Okay. I'm looking for syntax now that will express that I'm looking for a fixed point of the operation without separately testing for equality.

Answer (score 0):

better have more granular

```
import Data.List.Ordered                -- install data-ordlist

next f xs = nubSort $ map f xs
```

then

```
orbit f xs = snd $ until 
    (\(ys,xs) -> null $ minus ys xs)    -- nothing new to add
    (\(ys,xs) -> (next f $ union ys xs, ys))
    (next xs, xs)
```

you're supposed to call [`Data.List.Ordered.union`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/data-ordlist/0.4.5/doc/html/Data-List-Ordered.html#v%3aunion) on two *ordered* lists. (and `minus` too).